# Conditional Rendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, render

I need to show and hide elements condtionally in react. I know we can condtionally render by creating boolean value for each element and and by manupulating particular boolean state variable we can conditionally show and hide elements. is there is any ways condtionally show and hide elements by not setting boolean variable for each elemnt in useState?

Here is the code. is there any ways to condtionally show and hide by not creating variable in state

```
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    ele0: true,
    ele1: true,
    ele2: true,
  });
  let arr = [1, 2, 3];

  const handleOnChange = (index) => {
    setState({ ...state, [`ele${index}`]: !state[`ele${index}`] });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((ele, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
      {state[`ele${idx}`] &&    <h1>{`element${idx}`}</h1> }
          <button
            onClick={() => handleOnChange(idx)}
          >{`element ${idx} button`}</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    )
```

Comment: you mean without this `const [state, setState] `?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another component called `MyElement` to keep the text and its text toggle button. That way no need to handle multiple states of each element in one place. `MyElement` is responsible for its own state.

Try like this:

```js
const MyElement = ({ idx }) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <div key={idx}>
      {state && <h1>{`element${idx}`}</h1>}
      <button
        onClick={() => setState((prev) => !prev)}
      >{`element ${idx} button`}</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Array.from({ length: 3 }).map((ele, idx) => (
        <MyElement idx={idx} key={idx}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: @skay, check this out !!